# Using JS variables when filtering an array from EJS?

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, variables, ejs

I want to filter my users array by "username" variable from js.

Server side:

```
var users = data.filter(u => u.id.startsWith('user_')).map(u => u.value);
// [{"username": "arin2115", "someotherdata": "someotherdata"}, {"username": "tesla", "someotherdata": "someotherdata"}]

return res.render('admin/users', {users: users});
```

Client side:

```
<script>
  var someelement = document.getElementById("someelement");

  var username = "arin2115";

  var user = `<%-JSON.stringify(users.filter(x => x.username == "${username}")[0])%>`;

  someelement.innerHTML = user.someotherdata;
</script>
```

like something above, I have tried many ways to do it but any of them doesn't work.

Working solution from [@AngYC](https://stackoverflow.com/users/8888888/angyc):

```
var username = "arin2115";

var users = <%-JSON.stringify(users)%>;

var user = users.find(x => x.username == username);
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you open the `<%-` bracket, it means you are in a JavaScript context. You don't have to quote it again with `"${username}"` but rather use `username` directly, sample code below:

```
var user = `<%-JSON.stringify(users.filter(x => x.username == username)[0])%>`;
```

Your current solution means you are trying to match a username that is exactly `"${username}"`, which means you have to have following in your `users` for it to match:

```json
[{ "username": "\"${username}\"" }]
```

Comment: I already have tried that, but EJS returns me error - username is not defined. Because it's not a variable passed in render function, but a variable made in javascript file.

Comment: @KarcielloYT If this variable is in the JS code, then you have to return the whole `users` array to the client-side for it to filter from there. I suggest you share a bit more code so we can help better.

Comment: I have edited my post so there is a server side and client side code, but when doing that I also have done that properly by returning users array to client-side, thanks for your response.

Answer (score 0):

With your approach, the type of `user` is going to be a string, and therefore you're recieving your `user`s as a JSON parsed in a String format. As follows:

```js
var user = '[{"username":"x"}]';
```

I believe you are looking for a single user, and get the object itself, not a string representation of it.

So you may use this approach for ES2020 using optional chaining, please not that you might need polyfills for older browsers.

```js
var user = `<%- users.filter(x => x.username == "${username}")?.[0] %>`;
```

Using a classic implementation of this, making sure that the user exists before accessing the user, you may do the following:

```js
var user = `<%- users.filter(x => x.username == "${username}") %>`; 
if(user.length > 0) user = user[0];
```

At the end of both approachs you have the user variable as following:

```js
var user = { username: "x" }
```